# How to detect if there are any pending orders in mql5

Tags: mql5

I want to detect if there are any pending orders in mql5. I tried to use OrdersTotal, but it returns always 0 orders.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, it works on my MT5.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CheckIfOpenOrder()
  {
   int Orders   =  OrdersTotal();

   if(Orders > 0)
     {
      for(int i=0; i<Orders; i++)
        {
         double open_price  = OrderGetDouble(ORDER_PRICE_OPEN);
         string symbol      = OrderGetString(ORDER_SYMBOL);
         long order_magic   = OrderGetInteger(ORDER_MAGIC);
         long positionID    = OrderGetInteger(ORDER_POSITION_ID);
         double volume      = OrderGetDouble(ORDER_VOLUME_INITIAL);
         string type        = EnumToString(ENUM_ORDER_TYPE(OrderGetInteger(ORDER_TYPE)));

         MessageBox("Order: " + (string)i);
        }
     }

   else
     {
      MessageBox("Doesn't exist any order");
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```